# else cant read the variable "msg"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so basically I have some code that will look at a Reddit page and get the title, link, current upvotes, and how long ago it was posted. And if the links aren't the same it will send an embed to my discord, but if they are the same then it won't do anything but i want to edit the embed so it changes the current upvotes but in the else function it can't read the variable "msg".

I've thought to use Global but I cant make it work, can anyone help?

```
          if geta != oglink:
              print('new link')
              with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
                f.write(f"{geta}")
                f.close()
              print(oglink)
              print(geta)
              print(gettime.text)
              print(gettext.text)
              #global msg
              msg = await channel.send(embed=Newsembed)
              with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
                oglink = f.read()
                f.close()
              print("New Top reddit has been sent!")
          else:
              print(oglink)
              print(geta)
              print('Top reddit has not changed')
              
              await channel2.send('top reddit has not changed')
              global msg
              await msg.edit(embed=editembed)
```

Comment: You only define the variable in the `if` branch. If it doesn’t go into that branch because it goes into the other branch, then the variable isn’t defined.

Answer (score 0):

Put `global` in the declaration of the if statement, that way the variable msg will become global, like this:

```
          if geta != oglink:
              print('new link')
              with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
                f.write(f"{geta}")
                f.close()
              print(oglink)
              print(geta)
              print(gettime.text)
              print(gettext.text)
              #global msg
              global msg = await channel.send(embed=Newsembed)
              with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
                oglink = f.read()
                f.close()
              print("New Top reddit has been sent!")
          else:
              print(oglink)
              print(geta)
              print('Top reddit has not changed')
              await channel2.send('top reddit has not changed')
              await msg.edit(embed=editembed)
```

Comment: `global msg = await channel.send(embed=Newsembed)` is a syntax error. In any case, while moving `global` up is a good thing (well, probably `global` shouldn't be used *at all*) but in any case this won't fix the OP's error